# Страницу скроллит наверх при нажатии на попап от чата bitrix24?

Tags: битрикс24

Есть сайт - https://eco-drev.by/. На нем подключен чат от битрикса, в котором используется глобальный скрипт для работы чата, но при нажатии на сам попап чата, либо при его закрытии на крестик, скролл страницы сбрасывается и перебрасывает страницу в начало.
Я так понимаю это сам скрипт битрикса так делает, но как можно обойти эту проблему и написать хак, чтобы страница оставалась на месте, как при нажатии на сам попап, так и при нажатии на крестик?

Да, не работает именно в мобильной версии. В десктопе все хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой-же проблемой. Путем проб и ошибок нашёл "виновника" прыжков с отладчике браузера: свойство "overflow" со значением "auto".

Как оказалось виджет Б24 добавляет к тегу html свои стили:

- bx-touch
- crm-widget-button-mobile

А точнее эти:

- .bx-touch.crm-widget-button-mobile
- .bx-touch.crm-widget-button-mobile body

После убирания свойства "overflow" из данных стилей проблема с прыжками на мобильных исчезла.

Comment: Не сработало у меня. Все также скачет, и тут не похоже, что проблема только со стилями, тут наверное ещё что-то js делает..